# How to talk about a mailing list in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, modern-life

We have ([wiki](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursus_electronicus) with sources) new latin words for the email service (*cursus electronicus* or *cursus publicus electronicus*), a single email (*litterae electronicae* or *electrogramma, -tis n*) and email address  (*Inscriptio electrica* or *inscriptio cursualis electronica*). Now I want to talk about a mailing list.

A list might be *tabulae*, *index* or *catalogus*. I'm not sure wich fits best, but *catalogus* is rather greek and *tabulae* cannot be declined to plural. Let's try *index*.

The first idea is a list of mails: *index litterarum electronicarum* or (to emphasize the plural) *index epistularum electronicarum*

But mailing list is not really a list of mails, but of mail addresses or recipients: *index inscriptionum electricarum* or *index acceptorum epistularum electronicarum*

But in a practical sense a mailing list is not really a list of addresses, but a tool to write emails to many people at the same time. For better recognizability we may stick with *index*: *index ad epistulas electronicas producendum* or *mittendum* - but that is really clumsy and long.

**Does anyone have a good idea for a fitting word?**

Ideally we also have fitting verbs: maybe *se/aliquem in indicem ... referre* (subscribe), *se/aliquem ab indice ... eradere* (unsubscribe) and *epistula electronica ad personas indicis dare* (write to mailing list)

Comment: The same way as in several East-Asian languages today, and in some European languages today which I have knowledge of, new words can be created by using the first few or last syllables of key words. 셀카 (sel-ka), for instance, is the Korean word for ‘selfie’ (from self + camera). As is well known, we have ‘bus’ from ‘omnibus’, and Nordic languages have ‘bil’ from ‘automobile’. How about finding Latin sources for the same method, and create words such as *litterōnica*, Could such a word be created to get a less clumsy word for mailing list? After all, ‘mailing’ = ‘sending electronic mail’.

Answer (score 3):

Surely a mailing list is a list of email addresses, *index inscriptionum electronicarum* (where the last word would be the first to drop out for convenience, I suppose).
*To subscribe* would surely be *nomen dare* ("register," as in for a course).